# Problema con Scripts en Visual Studio Code

Tags: script, powershell, vscode

En cuanto abro Visual Studio Code, me aparece en la consola propia de VSCode, lo siguiente:

```
. : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 
porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más 
información, consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 3
+ . 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
Cargar los perfiles personales y de sistema tardó 643ms.
```

No se si tendrá o no que ver, pero unas horas antes había instalado node, npm y typescript(aunque realmente los actualice, ya que los tenia de antes).

El tema y mi urgencia ante este problema, es que estoy haciendo un curso de JavaScript donde se utiliza, en una sección, TypeScript. Entonces, esa fue la razón por la que me puse actualizar esas "herramientas".

Además, dado un momento del curso tengo que ejecutar el siguiente script:

```
tsc clase148.ts
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
tsc : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 porque la 
ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para obtener más información, 
consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ tsc clase148.ts
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Entre al link:

[About Execution Policies](http://https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170)

Pero sinceramente, no se que tengo que hacer.

Cabe aclarar que ejecutando el script anterior, de tsc, en una línea de comando propia de Windows 10, me lo ejecuta bien y sin problemas.

¿Cómo soluciono este error, problema?

Comment: lo solucionastes? tengo el mismo problema, gracias!!

Comment: @Rutx1 No, lamentablemente sigo teniendo ese problema. Asi que opte por utilizar la consola propia de windows

Comment: En visual studio, en la terminal no tiene que ser powershell, tienes que elegir cmd como script en windows

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, debes ejecutar el powershell como administrador y ejecutar el comando **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

Comment: yo podia usar yarn en cmd pero no podia usarlo en VSC. con tu solucion todo aarreglado. gracias

Comment: Se debe aplastar el comando y aplastar la letra O.

Comment: El comando que me funciono fue Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser unrestricted

Comment: @RubenPalavecino con ese comando en el vsc luego funca! thanks

Answer (score 10):

solo abre el power shell y ejecuta el siguiente comando **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted** esto solucionara tu problema y podras ejectar scripts en la consola de VS Code

Comment: Me sale un error cuando ejecuto eso.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy : Se denegó el acceso a la clave de Registro 'HKEY_LO
CAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell 
'. Para cambiar la directiva de ejecución para el ámbito (LocalMachine)   
predeterminado, inicie Windows PowerShell con la opción "Ejecutar como    
administrador". Para cambiar la directiva de ejecución para el usuario 
actual, ejecute "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".`

Comment: `En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy 
   ], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microso 
   ft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand`

Comment: Eso fue en la consola de VS Code, en la terminal propia de windows me sale lo siguiente:

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
"Set-ExecutionPolicy" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
"Set-ExecutionPolicy" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Answer (score 5):

1. Ejecutar windows + R --> gpedit.msc
2. ir a
   Plantillas administrativas> Componentes de Windows> Windows PowerShell>
3. Seleccionar Activar la ejecución de scripts, click derecho, editar
4. Seleccionar Habilitada y Permitir todos los scripts, Aplicar

Con eso ya debería poder ejecutar scripts el powershell.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy usando Visual Code instalado en Windows 10, ya instalado Node y
sin permisos de Administrador de Windows.

Para un proyecto TypeScript aL intentar crear un archivo `tsconfig.json` con el comando `'tsc --init'` me daba el mismo error "No se puede cargar el archivo `..\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1` porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema.".

En la consola de Visual Code apliqué:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser unrestricted`

Luego volví a aplicar el comando `'tsc --init'`, funcionó OK.